# C# cast generic type (like C++ user defined conversions)

Tags: c#, generics, casting

Is there a way in C# to perform a user defined conversion for generic types ?

for example:

```
class Stack<T> 
{
    private T x; //should be an array but doesn't matter for this example

    public Stack(T input)
    {
        x = input;
    }

    public Stack<Q> Convert<Q>(Stack<T> inputStack)
    {
        //what would go here ? The call is below.
    }
}

//main code
Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>(2);
Stack<long> longstack = stack.Convert<long>(stack);
```

I would imagine that the compiler can deduce that Q is long and T is int in the Convert function, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is extension method for standart Stack class (you can rewrite it a little and use like instance method in your own Stack class):

```
public static class MyStackExtensions
{
    public static Stack<TDest> Convert<TSrc, TDest>(
        this Stack<TSrc> stack, 
        Func<TSrc, TDest> converter = null)
    {
        if (stack == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("stack");
        var items = converter == null
            ? stack.Select(i => (TDest) System.Convert.ChangeType(i, typeof (TDest)))
            : stack.Select(converter);
        return new Stack<TDest>(items.Reverse());
    }
}
```

Convert stack from int to long using convert function - **no type params needed :-)**

```
var intStack = new Stack<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
var longStack = intStack.Convert(i => (long)i);
```

Or using standart conversion:

```
var intStack = new Stack<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
var longStack = intStack.Convert<int, long>();
```

Comment: great. This cleared it up. btw, what is the items.Reverse() for ? is it because it is a Stack ?

Comment: Yes, we must reverse items to preserve order.

Answer (score 3):

No, because class-level generic type parameters can't be auto-infered from usage.

> I would imagine that the compiler can deduce that Q is long and T is
>   int in the Convert function, but it doesn't seem to work.

Maybe, but at the end of the day, a generic type parameter doesn't belong to constructor. That is, you provide a generic argument to the type based on what constructor parameter/argument? What happens if there're more than a constructor parameter?

```
public class A<T>
{
    // Which one should be used to auto-infer T from usage?
    // Maybe the integer? Or the bool? Or just the string...?
    // Every choice seems a joke, because it would be absolutely
    // arbitrary and unpredictable...
    public A(int x, string y, bool z)
    {
    }
}
```

Now take your sample code as example. It has the same issue: what argument should be used from your `Convert` static method to infer generic type argument from usage? What happens if `Convert` has more than an argument...?

Comment: from the second line in the call to Convert, the compiler would know that stack is of type Stack<int> and that Q is of type long. Do you have any more information or link to the appropriate part of the spec ?

Comment: Oh! A downvote without throwing here a comment to improve my answer!

Comment: @tomatoRadar I've been trying to find the whole link and I don't find it. BTW, I'm not inventing a dogma here. C# works this way (I've been using generics since they were introduced in .net 2.0...), and you could argue "C# would do X", but anwyay, it would be in dreams because we can't change C# :)